# C buffer memory allocation

Tags: c, malloc

I'm quite new to C so please bear with my incompetence. I want to read an whole EXEcutable file into a buffer:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
long lSize;

fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
lSize = ftell(file);
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

char *buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*lSize);
fread(buffer, 1, lSize, file);
```

The file has 6144 bytes (stored correctly in lSize) but the size of my buffer is only 4 bytes, therefore only the MZ signature is stored in the buffer.

Why does malloc only allocate 4 bytes in this case?

**Edit:**
Probably the char buffer is terminated by the first 0 in the MZ header of the PE file. If I set the buffer to a certain value however, the whole file will be stored. If I set the buffer to int (= 4 bytes), the buffer won't be terminated but will be of course larger (vs. char = 1 byte). I just want to copy the file byte for byte with the null bytes as well.

**Edit 2:**
The buffer of course contains everything it should but if I try to write it to a new file with fwrite, it only wrote up to the first \0 (which is 4 bytes). I just got fwrite wrong. Fixed this. Sorry, the problem wasn't well defined enough.

Comment: Why do you think, that malloca allocates 4 bytes only?

Comment: How do you know it's allocating only 4 bytes (it should not, and I see no error in your code). How are you determining that only 4 bytes have been read/stored?

Comment: You don't have to use sizeof to learn the size of char. sizeof(char) is always 1. In C, "char" and "byte" are synonymous.

Comment: `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition. If the buffer only contains 4 bytes it is because `lSize == 4`.

Comment: The code looks correct. Is it possible that you're watching the contents of buffer in the debugger, as a null-terminated string, and seeing only 4 bytes because the fifth one is a null byte? Try examining the contents of buffer in a memory window before and after calling fread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `lSize` really does equal `6144` then your code will indeed allocate `6144` bytes and then read the entire contents of the file. If you believe that only 4 bytes are being read it is probably because the 5th byte is a zero. Thus when buffer is interpreted as a zero terminated string, it terminates at that point.

You can inspect the rest of your buffer by looking at `buffer[4]`, `buffer[5]`, etc.

As an aside, you don't need to cast the return from `malloc`, and `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition. Best practice is to write the `malloc` like this:

```
char *buffer = malloc(lSize);
```

But that will not change your results.

Comment: I think you might be correct. The DOS Header is \MZ220 and therefore terminated. But if I manually set the buffer to a large number, e.g. buffer[16000] the buffer will contain the whole file regardless of the 0.

Comment: I'd bet that you are looking at buffer as a null-terminated string in the debugger. Using printf will stop at the 0. If only 4 bytes were allocated you'd probably seg fault on the fread. Run a for loop and print buffer char by char, `printf("%c\n", buffer[i]);`

Comment: I don't understand your edit. Your existing code reads the entire file into buffer. It is already all there. But you can't treat it as a null-terminated string.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does malloc only allocate 4 bytes in this case?

Because you failed to `#include <stdlib.h>` (and cast the return value of `malloc()`).

---

**Do not forget to `#include <stdlib.h>`** so that the compiler knows `malloc` returns a value of type `void*` (rather than assuming it returns an `int`) and takes an argument of `size_t` type (rather than asuuming it is an `int`)

**Also do not cast the return value of `malloc`**. A value of type `void*` can be assigned to an object of pointer (to any type) type. Casting the return value makes the compiler silently convert `int` (assumed when `<stdlib.h>` was not included) to the type in the cast. Note the compiler would complain without the cast letting you know you had forgotten the include.

---

The real error is not `malloc` allocating the wrong amount (I believe it will allocate the correct amount anyway). **The real error is assuming malloc returns an int when it returns a void*.** `int` and `void*` can be passed differently (one in a register, the other on the stack for instance) or they have different representations (two's complement for `int` and segmented address for `void*`) or any other thing (most probably `sizeof (int) != sizeof (void*)`).

Comment: Huh? Are you sure about that?

Comment: Sure casting the return value of malloc is bad practice, but an error? I doubt this, as I've done this a one hundred thousand times (being from a C++ background, where it is not converted implicitly).

Comment: why casting should be a problem?

Comment: I understand you jumping on this opportunity to make a point about casting the result of `malloc()`, but if this is the cause, then the error is to fail to include `stdlib.h` and the cast only hides a useful warning. EDIT: after reading the other comments: see? Putting it this way confuses people.

Comment: As per the comments, the real error is the failure to include the correct header. The cast to the return value is a way to make the compiler silently accept the error.

Comment: Why would failing to include the right error result in `malloc` allocating only 4 bytes? And why would that not result in seg fault on the `fread`?

Comment: stdlib.h is included, I just thought it isn't necessary to write it in my post. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

how are you checking for the size of buffer, are you doing a `sizeof(buffer)`? In that case you are only seeing the size of a `pointer to int` which is 4 bytes. You cannot get the size of a buffer out of it's pointer. You must store it separately as you have done (in `lSize`).

If `malloc()` did not return `NULL` then your buffer is fine and the size is correct.